# True or false question about polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let, $\mathbb{R}[x]$ be a polynomial ring and let $J = (x)$. True/false: $J$ consists of all the polynomials of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ whose constant terms are $0$.

I know $J=(x)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$, and the statement is true. But, I don't exactly understand why. Could someone please help understand this? Thanks.

Comment: Hint : in $\mathbb{R}[X]$, the ideal $(X)$ is $\left\{ XP(X), \, P \in \mathbb{R}[X] \right\}$.

Comment: So what is $(x)$ by definition? How dow does an ideal generated by one element look like?

Comment: Take a polynomial - if it has zero constant term, is it in the ideal? If a polynomial with non-zero constant term is in the ideal, what other elements can you find in the ideal?

Comment: @MarkBennet Could you please explain in a bit details.

Comment: It is about understanding what an ideal is and what it means for an ideal to be generated by an element.

Answer (score 1):

An Ideal $I$ in a commutative (for simplicity) Ring $R$ is a subset which is an additive subgroup of $R$ and for which $ir\in I$ whenever $i\in I, r\in R$. The ideal generated by an element $x\in R$ is the smallest ideal of $R$ containing $x$ (the intersection of all such ideals is itself an ideal).

To sketch the ideas here, suppose $p(x)$ has constant term $0$, then $p(x)=xq(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$, and we therefore have $p(x)\in I$ by setting $i=x, r=q(x)$. An ideal containing $x$ must therefore contain all the polynomials with zero constant term.

Then the polynomials with zero constant term are an additive subgroup, satisfy the multiplicative rule for an ideal and contain $x$. So the Ideal of polynomials with zero constant term contains the ideal generated by $x$.

Therefore the ideal generated by $x$ must be equal to the ideal of polynomials with zero constant term.

There are some details to fill in.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. so every polynomial with constant $0$ term must be contained in the ideal. And, as $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to the quotient, nothing else can be contained in the ideal.

Comment: You should first write down an explicit isomorphism. How can you otherwise explain that every polynomial with constant term $0$ must lie in $(x)$, without using what the OP is trying to prove?